# How to add self-signed certificate to docker nginx:alpine

Tags: docker, nginx, certificates

This is my-compose.yml definition

```
nginx:
  image: "nginx:alpine"
  ports:
    - 5000:80
  links:
    - registry:registry
  volumes:
    - ./auth:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./auth/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

registry:
  image: registry:latest
  volumes:
    - ./registry-data:/var/lib/registry
```

I start docker as daemon on fly

```
sudo docker-compose -f my-compose.yml up -d
```

maybe I need to add my self-signed certificate to "nginx:alpine" docker, but how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what sort of hoops your Docker containers need to jump through, you can accomplish this with a `COPY` command in your DockerFile:

```
COPY /path/to/certificate.pem /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
COPY /path/to/certificate-key.key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
```

Some notes:

- if your certificates are in `.pem` format, do not use any transformation processes; simply rename `.pem` to `.crt`
- copy the renamed certificates to the proper certificate location for your nginx installation
- ensure nginx knows where the files are expected to be:

  ```
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
  ```

This should do what you need it to do

Comment: Thank you @matigo, I copy certificates inside container and check - is it present? sudo docker exec -it 705c3bb67bce cat /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt and sudo docker exec -it 705c3bb67bce cat /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key, Yes, certificates present. But result of https resuest is: "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority". Maybe I need to restart Nginx inside docker to accept new cetificates, or... I don't know